# Load Firebase remote config in Application class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Since Application is known for its global-variable usage. I was thinking maybe it's good to load Firebase remote config in onCreate() method in Application class and all variable will be stored as "public static" and with an initial value.

Just want to know if it is a good idea because I've tried to store remote-configs as private objects with classic getter/setter and that causes null-exceptions frequently.

Comment: I have tried to use it from a utility class. But I returned many null values. So what I did was apply this configuration from my main activity. And so use it in all my other activities and fragments. Always taking into account that a memory leak can occur, I always use the context of the main activity. I just pass getApplicationContext () to my methods or constructors. According to the documentation: _Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process._ [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use Application.  If you have (or ever will have) a multi-process app, some Firebase features may have problems with that.

There is no guarantee that putting a call to fetch() early on in your app will make the values available as soon as they're needed.  You should build your app taking into account that it may take some time to load Remote Config parameters.  If you absolutely require them at launch, make a load screen and start the fetch there, progressing only when they're finished loading.

There are different strategies for using Remote Config, and they're outlined in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html).

Comment: god, I was searching for a block entry like this - thank you @Doug Stevenson

Comment: "If you have (or ever will have) a multi-process app, some Firebase features may have problems with that." - Can you elaborate more on what problems exactly?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Firebase remote-configs?

In my experiences, I usually use Application onCreate() to start Firebase services.

Then gather the Firebase token and listen to its changes. I use SharedPref to store my Firebase token.

That is my approach.

The cause of null-exception is depended on different context. So, it is better if you show your implementation.

Comment: I mean Firebase Remote Config variables.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Comment: I see. And my suggestion is not using Application to do. The reason is Application is not guaranteed to keep all your mutable variable forever.

The reason you got your app crash with NullPointerException is the GC may collect your defined variables, and when your Firebase instance access it again, it was not there anymore.